# Create A JQuery Hover From Two Seperate Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'img[id$=_fav]', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().css("border-top-color", "#000");
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', 'img[id$=_fav]', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().css("border-top-color", "gray");
});
```

I am wondering how can I merge both of those into a single hover event or is this not possible using the 'live' way?

I want something like this:

```
$('body').on('hover', 'img[id$=_fav]', function(event) {
function(){ //mouse enter
$(this).parent().css("border-top-color", "#000");
}
function(){ //mouse leave
$(this).parent().css("border-top-color", "gray");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `function() { twice` for `mouseenter` and use `,` to separate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave events` like,

```
$('img[id$=_fav]').hover(function(event) {// use function() once for mouse enter event
   $(this).parent().css("border-top-color", "#000");
},function(){ //mouse leave, you missed a comma in your code
   $(this).parent().css("border-top-color", "gray");
});
```

Read [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover)

**Updated** if you want to use `hover` for `dynamically added elements` then you have to use **on()** with `mouseenter mouseleave events` as you are using,

**From [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

> *Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9:* The name `"hover"` used as a
>   shorthand for the string `"mouseenter mouseleave"`. It attaches a single
>   event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine
>   event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave.
>   Do not confuse the `"hover" pseudo-event-name` with the `.hover()` method,
>   which accepts one or two functions.

Comment: OP wants to hook hover event for dynamically created element. How direct hooking will do the job here? or am i missing anything.?

Comment: Will this code work for elements created in the future? Your code seems to be missing the live part.

Comment: @Nuvolari Please dont think about live. It was deprecated. Use .On instead.

Comment: Don't worry by 'live' I mean 'On' - its just easier to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to hook `hover event` on an element which was created/added dynamically into the `DOM`. Since we can't achieve the same syntax of `hover` with `on`, we could alternatively use the `event type` to divert the control flow. Technically speaking, `hover` will simply handle both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` behind the screen. Try using the following code,

```
$(document).on("hover",'img[id$=_fav]', function(e) {
  if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
      }
  else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
      }
});
```

### [DEMO based on 1.8 and below](http://jsfiddle.net/uNtwY/)

**Note :** *Please skip the above part. Just know about it for your future usage*

---

Since hover event was removed from Jquery after 1.9, But not .hover() function. You cant use it hereafter with latest libraries. Instead try to handle by using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` like below,

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {

    },
    mouseleave: function () {

    }
}, 'img[id$=_fav]');
```

### [DEMO based on latest versions of JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/uNtwY/1/)

Comment: Hi your code isn't working for me. Hover event isn't being fired.

Answer (score -2):

It's done exactly like you want: [see the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)